# Pointer to a vector of pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I'm learning C++ and I came across a similar situation in my assignment. Each of my attempts to solve this case came with a few questions so I simplified it here.

For this scenario, I'll use this class:

```
class Story {
    string _title;

    //a simple getter
    string getTitle(){ 
        return _title;
    }
};
```

Now in my main function, I have `stories`, a pointer of a vector with pointers to `Story`:

```
vector<Story *> * stories = function();
```

My objective is to access to the `_title` of the first `Story` in my vector (my vector size will always be greater than 0).

To do so, I tried a few methods that I thought would work:

```
//Attempt 1 (doesn't work)
*(stories)[0]->title(); 
    //I thought `*(stories)[0]` returns the first `Story*`
    /** Error message:
     * error: ‘class std::vector<Story*>’ has no member named ‘title’
     */
//Attempt 1.5 (equivalent to Attempt 1)
*(stories).at(0)->title();

//Attempt 2 (works)
stories->at(0)->title(); 
    //Aren't `*(stories).at(0)` and `stories->at(0)` the same?
    //Since Attempt 1.5 failed, there as to be a difference..

//Attempt 3 (doesn't work)
stories->begin()->title(); 
    //I thought `stories->begin()` returns the first `Story*`
    /** Error message:
     * error: request for member ‘title’ in 
     * ‘* stories->std::vector<Story*>::begin().__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Story**, std::vector<Story*> >::operator->()’, which is of pointer type ‘Story*’
     * (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
     */
```

I understand why my Attempt 2 works, but I don't get why 1, 1.5 and 3 don't.

Just in case, I compile using these options:

```
--std=c++11 -O0 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra
```

Comment:  #3 looks like a typo.

Comment: `*(stories).at(0)` is not the same as `stories->at(0)`.     `(*stories).at(0)` is.   Note the `*` is inside the `()`, so the meaning is different.

Comment: Imagine if `stories->begin()` returned the first `Story*`, how would you get the second one? Surely it must return something that you can increment to get the next `Story*`, and that wouldn't be the *value* of the first `Story*`, would it?

Comment: I just tried out like @Peter for Attempt 1 and 1.5. I never noticed the `*` add to be inside. There was in fact a typo as @TrebledJ "pointed" out for Attempt 3 and  @DavidSchwat explanation help for the iterator. Thank you all.

Comment: C++ thrives on value semantics. No matter **how** to do this, please don't. `vector` can contain Story's directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) returns an iterator (pointing to the beginning of the vector) and an iterator has to be dereferenced, to get the element it is pointing to.

With `begin()->` (or `(*stories->begin())`) you dereference that iterator and you get a `Story *`, but `Story *` does not have member `title`. So it has to be `(*stories->begin())->title()`

Or use [front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) as it returns a reference to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

In case of your attempt 3,

`stories->begin()` will return an iterator, to print the value stored at the position pointed by iterator try something like this

```
*(stories->begin())
```

Comment: Indeed, everything works with this: `(*stories->begin())->title();`